# use assertion with junit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

From a Table, I get list of String's and would like to check that when `val != "A"`, a string `"x"` exists in the list of table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NbRow; j++)
{          
  if (val[i] == "A")
  {
     assertFalse("");          
  }
  else
  {        
    list.add(myTable.getValue(j, 0));      
    //need to check here the string exists in the list using assertTrue 
  }
}
```

How do I check that string X exists using assertion?

Comment: On top of my head this might be what you want: `assertTrue(list.contains("string"))` ?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`, use `equals()`, e.g. in your above code do `"A".equals(val[i])` -- putting the constant string on the left-hand side prevents `NullPointerException` if `val[i]` should ever be `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

assertThat(list, hasItem("string"));
```

[Edit]
And if you like so:

```
if (val[i] == "A")
{
   Assert.fail("");          
}
```

can be written as:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;

assertThat(val[i], is(not(equalTo("A"))));
```

Comment: There's no need for bringing in a whole library when there's [`Collection.contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @Philipp No there is no need to but if you like to write your asserts in a more DSL manner I'd recommend it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!val.equals("A"))
{
    assertTrue(list.contains("x"));
}
```

Comment: Don't `!=`, but `!equals()` please :)

Comment: To be able to use assertTrue like that you need to import the Junit AssertTrue dependency with static.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to use null pointer exception safe string comparison

```
  if (!"A".equals(val[i]))
  {
    assertTrue(list.contains("x"));
  }
```